# PDO Sign up form successfully inserting into database but try/catch block catching every time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Okay so I have a sign up PHP script (using PDO) that validates the inputted data, checks to see if the user already exists (by checking email) and then finally inserts the data into the database to create a new user. On successful submission however, the data inputs into the database but the try-catch block returns "Damn. Couldn't add user to database".

Is it a case of not needing a try-catch block for the SQL insert?

Thanks

```
           // Process details (after validation above)
            require_once(ROOT_PATH . "inc/db_connect.php"); 

            //clean the input if we have a db connection

            $firstname = clean_string($db, $firstname);
            $lastname = clean_string($db, $lastname);
            $email = clean_string($db, $email);
            $password = clean_string($db, $password);
            $repeatpassword = clean_string($db, $repeatpassword);
            $age = clean_string($db, $age);
            $jobtitle = clean_string($db, $jobtitle);
            $priceperhour = clean_string($db, $priceperhour);
            $bio = clean_string($db, $bio);
            $portfolio = clean_string($db, $portfolio);
            $experience = clean_string($db, $experience);
            $jobtitle = clean_string($db, $jobtitle);

           // Check whether email has been used before

            try {
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT designers.email 
                    FROM connectdDB.designers 
                    WHERE designers.email = ? 
                    UNION SELECT developers.email 
                    FROM connectdDB.developers 
                    WHERE developers.email = ?
                    UNION SELECT employers.email 
                    FROM connectdDB.employers 
                    WHERE employers.email = ?
                ");
                $result->bindParam(1, $email);
                $result->bindParam(2, $email);
                $result->bindParam(3, $email);
                $result->execute();

                $total = $result->rowCount();
                $row = $result->fetch();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Damn. Data could not be retrieved.";
                exit;
            }

            if ($total > 0) {
                $message = "Email already taken. Please try again.";
            }else{
                // Encrypt password
                $password = salt($password);

                try {
                    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO connectdDB.developers 
                        (firstname, lastname, email, password, location, portfolio, jobtitle, age, priceperhour, experience, bio, datejoined) 
                        VALUES 
                        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now())");
                    $result->bindParam(1, $firstname);
                    $result->bindParam(2, $lastname);
                    $result->bindParam(3, $email);
                    $result->bindParam(4, $password);
                    $result->bindParam(5, $location);
                    $result->bindParam(6, $portfolio);
                    $result->bindParam(7, $jobtitle);
                    $result->bindParam(8, $age);
                    $result->bindParam(9, $priceperhour);
                    $result->bindParam(10, $experience);
                    $result->bindParam(11, $bio);
                    $result->execute();

                    $total = $result->rowCount();
                    $row = $result->fetch();

                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Damn. Couldn't add user to database.";
                    exit;
                }

                header("Location:" . BASE_URL . "sign-in.php?status=registered");
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing what the raised Exception is for?

Comment: How would I see that? The "Damn. Couldn't add user to database." exception is in the sql insert try-catch block

Comment: `echo $e->getMessage();`. FWIW, I'm not sure why you're attempting to fetch the INSERT? Copy/Paste error maybe?

Comment: Ah! I don't know why I was fetching either - I removed it and it's working as it should. Cheers!

Comment: Ha, not a problem. Anytime. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching how much rows -> `$row = $result->fetch();` was failing as there were no rows to fetch (in its nature as it is a new user), causing the catch.